# jQuery on("error") not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

I am trying to hide an image when there is no image found.

.js file:-

```
jQuery("#imgUrl").error(function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
});
```

jsp:-

```
<img id="imgUrl" src="{imgSrcUrl}" alt="image")/>
```

Firefox and IE browsers its working when image file is not available.  Please help.
Example:- imgSrcUrl => src="/images/category/aline.jpg" and this image file is not available.

Comment: My guess is the error handler is happening before you bind to it. i wonder if it propagates... add this to the `<head>` after including jQuery to test:  `$("body").on("error",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.id,e.target.src);
})`

Answer (score 2):

### Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/XaXBg/2/)**

Try this

Put this code in the head tag

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#imgUrl").error(function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I see this working only once I am the page for the first time.  I have a form submission to reload my page.  Upon reload it fails again. F5 - refresh also fails (only in Chrome)

Comment: @user1769790 May be problem with your remaining code,Please Post your code

Comment: I spent some time in google search for this issue and it is evident that Chrome got this issue.  Suggestions I found are:- 1. use a plugin from available in github. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached